# Elasticsearch - Standard tokenizer splits words by dot when it follows a number

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

I have an email field that uses the standard tokenizer. An email "john.smith@example.com" it is split into "john.smith" and "example.com" which is an expected behavior for me. However if the email is "john.smith@example2.com" it splits it into "john.smith", "example2", "com" - the latter part is split by the dot.

This means when I search using query "example.com" I will get list of records with emails in that domain, but if I search for "example2.com" I won't have any results even if there are records with such email address.

Is there some workaround I could do to have the same behavior, that is, standard tokenizer not splitting by the dot when there is a number? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try use [chargroup-tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-chargroup-tokenizer.html) .

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "tokenizer": {
    "type": "char_group",
    "tokenize_on_chars": [
      "@"
    ]
  },
  "text": "john.smith@example2.com"
}
```

Token

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "john.smith",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 10,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "example2.com",
      "start_offset": 11,
      "end_offset": 23,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```